# ExpressJS shows request body as empty when it isn't empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, xmlhttprequest

I have a website and an express server running.
In the website, the user can input their username and password.
When they click the login button, the request is sent to the server with the username and password in the request body as a JavaScript object.

Here's the website code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Log In</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Log In</h1>

    <div id="i">
      <input type="text" name="u" id="u" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="p" id="p" placeholder="Password">

     <input type="submit" onclick="login()" value="Log In">
     <div id="msg"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
let u = document.getElementById("u");
let p = document.getElementById("p");
let msg = document.getElementById("msg");

let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log("Server request is ready. Press login to send request.")
    }
};

//login function triggered when user clicks login
function login() {
  data = {
  "username": u.value,
  "password": p.value
  }
  xhttp.open("POST", "SERVER_URL", true);
  xhttp.send(data)
}
```

But on the server-side, the request body shows empty:

```js
// environment variables
const client = process.env['MAIN_CLIENT'];

// imports
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


//init
const app = express();



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));//app.use(bodyParser);
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`)
})


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", client);
  
  next();
});


app.post(`/data`, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)

  u = req.body.u;
  p = req.body.p;
  data = process.env; 
  console.log("----------------") 
  

  if (data[u] == p) {
    console.log(`\n-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/\nA user just logged in.\nUsername: ${u}\n-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-//-/ \n`)
    res.send(true)
  }
  else{
    console.log("no")
    res.send(false)
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {console.log('ready!')});
```

Whenever I try to log in, it shows the username as `undefined`. The request body shows as `{}`
Also, the variable `CLIENT` is the website URL.
Am I sending the request in the wrong way? Am I accessing the request body wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should wrap all the necessary code in the `login()` function: get the input value, init the XMLHttpRequest, send the request
- You need to provide the `Content-Type` for the request, it could be `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` because you've used 2 necessary middlewares on the server-side. In the below code, I use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is described in the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

```
//login function triggered when user clicks login
function login() {

  // get input value
  let u = document.getElementById("u").value;
  let p = document.getElementById("p").value;
  let msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;

  // init the request
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "SERVER_URL", true);

  // Send the proper header information along with the request
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
    }
  }
  xhttp.send(`username=${u}&password=${p}`);
  
}
```

Comment: When I log the body, it shows this: `{
  username: '[object HTMLInputElement]',
  password: '[object HTMLInputElement]'
}`

Comment: I edited my answer. I forgot `.value` to get the value from the input field

Answer (score 1):

Use  `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` and try making request once again. Your request headers may not be enough for the backend to understand that you are sending json data.

Comment: well, that opens up a new problem. i've called the `setRequestHeader` function after calling `open` and before calling `send`. and then there's an error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.`

Answer (score 0):

In the `login` function, you are sending `username` and `password` as a key and accessing wrong keys on the server-side:

```
app.post(`/data`, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const data = process.env; 
  console.log("----------------") 
 
  if (data[u] == p) {
    console.log(`\n-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/\nA user just logged in.\nUsername: ${u}\n-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-//-/ \n`)
    res.send(true)
  }
  else{
    console.log("no")
    res.send(false)
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this: `const { u, p } = req.body;` and it didn't work. It looks like the entire `req.body` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify to send data.

```
function login() {
  data = {
  "username": u.value,
  "password": p.value
  }

  xhttp.open("POST", "/token", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

Just one more note, express contains its own parsers, no need to add external parsers.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(express.json())
```